# spring websocket : SubProtocolWebSocketHandler

Tags: spring-websocket

I have stability problems with Spring web-sockets. Sometimes I have a similar exception to that describe in https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12812.

The patch is not available, then I have implemented my own code with a custom SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.

```
public class WBSSubProtocolWebSocketHandler extends SubProtocolWebSocketHandler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WBSSubProtocolWebSocketHandler.class);

    public WBSSubProtocolWebSocketHandler(MessageChannel clientInboundChannel, SubscribableChannel clientOutboundChannel) {
        super(clientInboundChannel, clientOutboundChannel);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        super.afterConnectionClosed(session, status);
        LOG.debug("WebSocket Connection closed for client with session ID {}", session.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        // WebSocketHandlerDecorator could close the session
        // https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12812
        if (!session.isOpen()) {
            LOG.warn("WebSocket Connection established for client with session ID {} was closed.", session.getId());
            return;
        }

        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
        LOG.debug("WebSocket Connection established for client with session ID {}", session.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) throws Exception {
        super.handleTransportError(session, exception);
        LOG.warn("WebSocket transport error for client with session ID {}", session.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage message) throws Exception {
        super.handleMessage(session, message);
        LOG.debug("Websocket incoming message ({}) from client with session ID {}", message.getPayload().toString(), session.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws MessagingException {
        super.handleMessage(message);
        LOG.debug("Websocket incoming message : {}, header {}", message);
    }

}
```

Now my problem is to reproduce the exception to see if the problem is solved. I tried various ways, but without success. I can not reproduce the closing of the connection. Does anyone have an idea?

We also have a second problem. The client application (angularjs application) sometimes reports that the socket-web connection is lost. But I do not understand why because on the server I have no error / warning in the logs.
How can I identify the problem and reproduce it?